# Search on Click with Jquery's Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, youtube

I am trying to simulate the Youtube Autocomplete Search experience.

I can't find the option when the viewer clicks on a listed item and is automatically proceeded to search for said item.

My coding is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = ['array1','array2'];
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $j("input#directorySearch").autocomplete(data);
  });
</script>
```

The above code will allow the user to click on of the listed items, however, it will fill the search box rather than automatically searching.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I wanted similar behaviour, using jQueryui's default autocomplete widget. The trick is to use the 'select' event, but submitting from your select-handler will not give the desired results, because the input will not yet have the selection filled in.

The following code works for me though:

```
$("input#searchbox").autocomplete({
  source: autocomplete,
  select: function(event, ui) { 
    $("input#searchbox").val(ui.item.value);
    $("#searchform").submit();
  }
})
```

(in the example above, 'autocomplete' is a url that points to the completion source)

Where input#searchbox is the actual input entry, and #searchform is its parent form. Basically, you need to fill the input before submitting yourself.

Comment: How do i do this in asp.net please?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something like:

```
$('.autocomplete ul li').live("click", function() {
  $("form#search").submit();
});
```

Where the click event on your option list triggers a form submit for your search form??

Comment: Just came back trying this solution but apparently, the form will not submit. It appears that there is another listener, for when the item is click it will then fill in the input form first.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I used something simple such as [Bassistance.de](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)

I moved on to using another library by [devBridge](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/)

devBridge has a option called "onSelect:" which allow me to auto-submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$j("input#directorySearch").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
  $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Official documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result#handler

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$( "#search" ).autocomplete(
    {
         source:'/search-terms.php',
         focus: function(event, ui) {
             $("input#search").val(ui.item.label);
         },
         select: function(event, ui) {

            $("#searchform button").click(); }
    })
});
```

I am using this working fine :)