# Select first jquery UI result automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery Autocomplete to search a local database of cities. Here is the code:

```
$('#txt_search_city').autocomplete({
    source: url,
    delay: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#id_city" ).val( ui.item.id );
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    },
    focus: function( event, ui ) { event.preventDefault(); }
});
```

I'd like the first returned value to be selected by default (like it works on facebook). So essentially, if they just hit enter they will trigger the selection of the first result.

I thought that's what `autoFocus: true` did, but it isn't working. Not showing errors, just not selecting the first result.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Autofocus](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-autoFocus) will highlight the first record..

Your code would then just need to include `autoFocus: true`, like below:

```
$('#txt_search_city').autocomplete({
    source: url,
    delay: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#id_city" ).val( ui.item.id );
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    },
    focus: function( event, ui ) { event.preventDefault(); }
});
```

Comment: awesome, exactly what I needed

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be outdated. I had the same problem.
Just use `.autocomplete({autoFocus: true})` 
I'm using jquery-ui-1.10.0.min and it works now.
No plug is needed.

Comment: It causes the first result to get focused , but it is not actually selected

Comment: Yes. The user must press enter to confirm the autocomplete. I don't think it's wise to auto select and load the first hit after the user typed only two or three characters.