# How To Select First Element in AutoComplete dropdown list

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Can any one help me how to select first element of autocomplete dropdown list if no element is
selected? I tried with autoFocus. working for key board events. If I use mouse,  the first element is not selecting which is auto focused.

Comment: what kind of autocomplete? jquery? bootstrap? can you add some code what youve tried so far?

Comment: Simply go to www.redbus.in and start enter a city name. Don't enter complete city name and go to next field.Even though if you don't enter complete city name automatically the first one will be selected. Like That I need.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I opened a similar question, as the answers suggested here did not work for me. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591954/autocomplete-how-to-get-automatically-value-on-focus-if-no-values-selected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first jquery UI result automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243441/select-first-jquery-ui-result-automatically)

Answer (score 3):

visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9243511/2393573) for answer

```
$('#txt_search_city').autocomplete({
source: url,
delay: 0,
autoFocus: true,
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#id_city" ).val( ui.item.id );
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
},
focus: function( event, ui ) { event.preventDefault(); }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `focus` event to fill the textbox with the focused item's value:

```
$("#autocomplete2").autocomplete({
    // ...
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/aupq9/)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the autoFocus option: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7419

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$('selector').autocomplete({selectFirst:true});
```

Comment: From where does this came from ? I cannot find any reference to `selectFirst` in jquery ui sources or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Check the example code in the above link. Hope this will help.

```
$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: projects,
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
    $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
    $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
    $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );
    return false;
 }
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You have to just trigger select event of jquery to get first option selected.

```
$("#ElementID").autocomplete({
      source: availableList
 })._trigger('select');
```

You can find a detailed answer here: [Language Lassi: Select first option using jQuery Autocomplete](http://languagelassi.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-select-first-option-using-jquery-autocomplete.html)